# Queries on interface implementation with appollo/neo4j-graphql-js not working

Tags: javascript, neo4j

My first question on StackOverflow.

**What am I trying to achieve:**
I'm implementing a back-end Graphlql service with Apollo server and the neo4j-graphql-js plugin.

I'm able to get a working solution up and running where I'm able to create and query nodes via the service. However, I'm not able to select nodes based on the interface the different types in my schema implement.

(the following is just a test schema so don't be distracted by content ;-) )

```js
interface Animal{
  name: String
}

type Bird implements Animal{
  name: String
  Beak_shape: String
}

type Mammal implements Animal{
  name: String
  Fure_type: String
}

type Query{
  animals: [Animal]
  birds: [Bird]
  mammals: [Mammal]
}
```

So query{ Bird{ etc, works fine, however when I do

```
{
  animals{
    name
  }
}
```

The result is

```
  "data": {
    "animals": []
  }
```

However, I would expect nodes in the result (one for Bird and one for Mammal).

```js
import { neo4jgraphql } from "neo4j-graphql-js";

export const typeDefs = `
interface Animal{
  name: String
}

type Bird implements Animal{
  name: String
  Beak_shape: String
}

type Mammal implements Animal{
  name: String
  Fure_type: String
}

type Query{
  animals: [Animal]
  birds: [Bird]
  mammals: [Mammal]
}
`;

export const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        animals: neo4jgraphql, 
        birds: neo4jgraphql, 
        mammals: neo4jgraphql
    }
};
```

So what am I doing wrong?
In the example project of neo4jgrapql-js movie example there is an interface / type example but it doesnt seem to be used and I cant find anything on the interface that helps me to resolve this issue.

Comment: isn't this typescript?

Comment: @Jerodev no, it is `graphql` type definition

Comment: I think `Handle interface types` is a feature to be implemented in `neo4j-graphql-js`, [see feature list](https://github.com/neo4j-graphql/neo4j-graphql-js#features)

Comment: Roy, how did I mist that! thanks for the notice. That explains it. Thanks.